# Pygame шахматная доска 8х8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Короче я делаю что-то на подобии шахмат! и пытаюсь на пайгейм расчертить поле, но вот не задача, оно все время какое-то кривое и косое! Что делать с этим не знаю, перепробовал все что знаю! Код который снизу лучшее что вышло!

```
import pygame as pg 
pg.init()

RES = WEDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800

sc = pg.display.set_mode(RES)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLEDZOLOT =(238,232,170)
OHRA = (160,82,45) 

FPS = 60

size = 100
y = 0

clock = pg.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()

    count = 0
    
    for run in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            if y % 2 == 0:
                x += 100 
            if count % 2 == 0:
                pg.draw.rect(sc, BLEDZOLOT, [size*x, size*y, size, size])
            else:
                pg.draw.rect(sc, OHRA, [size*x, size*y, size, size])
            count += 1
        y += 1
        

    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
            pg.draw.rect(sc, BLEDZOLOT, [size*x, size*y, size, size])
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(sc, OHRA, [size*x, size*y, size, size])
```

Comment: Благодарю за код!

Answer (score 0):

это немножко сэкономит ваше время и увеличит скорость программы)

```py
import pygame as pg 

RES = WEDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600

sc = pg.display.set_mode(RES)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLEDZOLOT = (238, 232, 170)
OHRA = (160, 82, 45) 

FPS = 60

size = 75

clock = pg.time.Clock()

board = pg.Surface((600, 600))

for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
            pg.draw.rect(board, BLEDZOLOT, [size * x, size * y, size, size])
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(board, OHRA, [size * x, size * y, size, size])

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit()
    
    sc.blit(board, (0, 0))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```